# Creating an upload form + inserting data into database using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, razor

I'm trying to create a simple form in which a user can input their personal details and also upload a file. The user's details then get inserted into a database and the file gets uploaded to a particular folder; I've got the two working separately but I would like them to work at the same time, ideally with the same 'submit' button and/or POST request.

Here's a tidy version of code so far:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:true,
        uploadText:"Upload")               
</form>


if(IsPost) {
  var n = Request.Form["name"];

  var fileSavePath = "";
  var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
  string file = "afilename";

  fileType = Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile.FileName);    
  fileName = file + fileType;

  fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Folder/" + fileName);
  uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;user id=user;password=pass;"))
  {
    string insert = "INSERT INTO Items VALUES ('" + file + "','" + n + "')";

    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert,con))
    {
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
    } 
  }
}
```

The problem I have is when requesting the form values on post:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO Items VALUES ('" + fileName + "','" + n + "')";
```

On the line above, the variable 'fileName' is inserted into the database ok, whereas 'n' is returned blank, so this line becomes:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO Items VALUES ('afilename.jpg','')";
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal using this method?

Comment: Please read this: [Preventing SQL Injection in ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492403/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ADO-NET)

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the link - I definitely need more education when it comes to SQL injection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your form tag to this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```